# Getting input from form results in null error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why it gives me a null error for this code. Basically I want to get the input from a form and do some javascript with it.

Here is jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2rz7wjd9/

The error is at line 56 or here at the querySelector line. Cannot read property of null.

```
document.querySelector('#book-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const title = document.querySelector('#book-name').value;
  const author = document.querySelector('#book-author').value;
  const pages = document.querySelector('#book-pages').value;


  const book = new Book(title,author,pages);

  console.log(book);
})
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle, seems to work fine for me with no errors, can you double-check the error still happens in your JSFiddle? If not, can you update it to have the error? Thanks.

Comment: console gives me the error at : document.querySelector('#book-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {} (basically, its telling me that when I select the form, its null.)

Comment: Ok but we can't reproduce that, so we can't fix it. There must be some difference between your code and the JSFiddle version. maybe in your code, you're placing this JavaScript before the form element, so it doesn't exist when you try to add the event listener to it? Just a guess, but that's quite a common cause of this sort of issue.